# Light pulses and energy-time uncertainty principle

Tags: visible-light, photons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Suppose we have a monochromatic light beam. We put an obstacle between source and observer and remove it repeatedly by certain frequency such that observer sees an oscillating intensity of light. Will the observer see different frequencies or only the original frequency? Does the energy-time uncertainty principle apply in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncertainty and wave-trains](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72788/)

Comment: Richard: in the duplicate question I've posted the envelope function is a gaussian so you have a wave packet. However exactly the same analysis applies when your modulating function is oscillatory, like the removal and replacement of your obstacle. The original frequency spectrum is convolved with the Fourier transform of your modulating function.

Comment: I suggest [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OOmSyaoAt0) as well. It basically talks about the energy-time uncertainty principle in very understandable terms and also deals with the situation where you periodically interrupt a light wave.